# Kotlin property not accessed when object loaded with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

If I load instances from the following classes with JPA/Hibernate and access the `x` property, the value is `0`. If I set a breakpoint on the property, it is never reached. So it looks like the implementation is completely ignored here.

Reduced to the relevant parts the code looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
abstract class Base {
    @Transient
    open val x = 1
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("D")
class Derived : Base() {
    @Transient
    override val x = 2
}
```

However, if I implement the getter explicitly, it works:

```
override val x get() = 2
```

As far as I know the Kotlin compiler doesn't generate a backing field in this case, but it should generate a getter method, since the property is not `private`. In the end there should be a method in both cases.

So what is the difference, that leads to the strange behavior, that `x` is `0` and the real property is never accessed?